# Is it right or wrong to use forms of words that aren't in any dictionaries?

Tags: word-usage, affixes, derivational-morphology

I want to use the word `ataractically` in a formal piece of writing. A derived form of `ataraxia`, I'd like to use it in a sentence like this:

> This is the most ataractically candid thing I've ever written.

Is it acceptable to use `ataractically`, a word which I cannot find in a single dictionary, and which only has a couple of results in Google?

`ataraxically` is another possible form.

Besides whether it may be correct or not, is an audience likely to understand it? Assume they're highly educated and well-read.

**I created a new question as I realised "ataractically" probably isn't going to be understood by 90% of my audience:**
[A better way of articulating 'ataractically candid'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104400/a-better-way-of-articulating-ataractically-candid)

Comment: Why would you want to use a word that nobody else would understand?

Comment: Forgetting the particular word choice, the general question, yes, of course you can use words that are not explicitly stated in a dictionary. There are too many possible ways to extend existing words in a well-formed manner to list. These would not be considered neologisms. 'Neologistic' not in a dictionary...'neologistically' the same... 'paraneologistically'... 'paraneologisticalness' = the state of being almost a new word...none of these words are in a dictionary.

Comment: Surely, to use it would be insegrevious.

Answer (score 6):

I've never seen any grammar rule that specifically says one cannot use the word *ataractically*; so I'd say it is not wrong to use it; but neither is it fully acceptable, because few people will understand it.

To my mind, the usual meaning of *[ataraxia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ataraxia#Noun)* (“(literary, Greek philosophy) A pleasure that comes when the mind is at rest”) does not lead directly to the usual meaning of *[ataractic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ataractic#Adjective)* (adj., “That has a tranquilizing effect” or noun,  “(medicine) A drug that is used to tranquilize; a tranquilizer”).  Moreover, the meaning of “ataractically candid” seems ambiguous; I don't see it as useful if you intend to communicate clearly.  A tiny number of English speakers know the meanings of *ataraxia* and *ataractic* and a vanishingly small number will get some meaning from  “ataractically candid”.

Comment: In fact, "ataractically candid" seems a little oxymoronic to me in that *"ataraxia"* connotes tranquilized, relaxed, and candid conveys a sense of clarity and forthrightness.

Comment: From "[La Palabra Dicha](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/poemas.html)", by Octavio Páz:
_En otra galaxia, ¿Cómo se dice ataraxia?_

Answer (score 4):

I'm highly educated and well-read, but I've never heard of either *ataraxia* or *ataractically*. Still, if you think your readers will understand it and not think you're being hopelessly pretentious, then there's no reason why you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Even if OP moves in very rarefied circles indeed, and he could reasonably expect his audience to understand the term, I think I'd have to say such usage would *always* be "hopelessly pretentious".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Apparently you don’t read peer-reviewed technical journals much.  This stuff is all over the place there.

Comment: @tchrist: Given [0 results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22ataractically%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books, and [only a single relevant instance](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22ataractically%22&oq=%22ataractically%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j62.3018&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on Google Internet for *ataractically*, one might suppose such (hopelessly pretentious) peer reviewers have to review each other's work, since no-one else does.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You misread me. I mean that it is normal to read hard-to-find words of Graeco-Roman extraction is such journals. I was not referring to that word in particular. Try reading biomedical journals for a while to see what I mean. Or linguistics.  Or to lesser extent, computer science, except insofar as it intersects with the others. In any event, given that *ataraxia* itself is well attested, all that remains is applying standard rules of derivational morphology to derive valid forms. Doesn’t mean anybody will understand it, though.

Comment: @tchrist: Ah well. Actually, I overstated my case. There are ***four*** relevant instances of the spelling [ataraxically](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22ataraxically%22&oq=%22ataraxically%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l2.2401&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on the Internet, plus 3-4 on Google Books. And for all I know, I might have come across the word when studying for my degree (which included Lit Crit) - but if so, I don't regret my decision not to bother remembering it.

Answer (score 3):

*OED 1* has *ataraxy*, with variants *ataraxie*, *ataraxia*, but offers no recorded adjectival form. One of the three citations it provides suggests an alternative:

> **1864** R. BURTON *Dahome* II.98 The ataraxy and the *comme il faut* calm that characterizes the more refined Anglo-Tropical mind.

*Ataractically candid* feels wrong; you seem to be speaking of a candour originating in ataraxy, but this suggests candour marked by ataraxy.

In any case, I, too, am highly educated and well-read and I had to look up *ataraxia*. If you are not addressing an audience familiar with Hellenistic philosophies I suggest *serenely* instead.