# A better way of articulating 'ataractically candid'

Tags: synonyms, phrase-requests

I'm trying to convey the sense of a rare moment of tranquility in the mind of a confused, flawed and tormented character.

> This is the most ataractically candid thing I've ever written.

This occurs at the end of a sincere, formal letter to a business partner asking for forgiveness.

I want to convey that the candour comes from the rare state of ataraxia the character is feeling at the time. Rare because they suffer from extreme bipolar disorder, and they are out of their mind more often than not.

Comment: This is a fun discussion topic, but not a good fit for ELU (we don't give style suggestions). I will say that that particular word is pretty obscure, and without context, is hard to figure out. A more common word that seems to capture your general intent might be 'lucidly'.

Comment: @Mitch I don't see that addresses style to any greater extent than  the run-of-the-mill *word-request* questions we field all the time, from which it only differs in point of being unusually and gratifyingly specific.

Comment: @StoneyB Nearly all word request questions are unconstructive or too localized or general reference. Consequently they are discouraged by Stack Exchange staff (except when they have redeeming value because they are of real linguistic or etymological interest to experts). The fact that this policy gets ignored a lot does not make them any more on topic.

Comment: @StoneyB Then by all means let us close them; but let's not start doing so with one that is refreshingly well written.

Comment: @StoneyB: I think maybe you meant to direct that comment at MetaEd, instead of yourself? (Or was that an attempt to depict a confused, flawed, and tormented mind?)

Comment: @StoneyB: My compliment/complaint/reason for voting to close is simple. This is an interesting issue but is worded as a writing style suggestion which is better served somewhere else. If the question were reworded as asking for a suggestion of a _synonym_ of  'ataractically' with this or that nuance, I'd most likely then vote to close as GR ('LMGTFY/thesaurus'). That's the culture here. Oh...forget culture...the OP should have done some _minimal_ looking himself, and a better explanation for us to go on.

Comment: @J.R. I think you are falling into the etymological fallacy when you use *tormented* to mean *twisted*. :)

Comment: @StoneyB: I was merely quoting the O.P. (maybe I should've used quotes?) :^)

Comment: Think more of lit crit than grammar.

Answer (score 2):

As I suggested in my answer to your previous question, I like *serenely*, which to me suggests  a haven after a tempestuous journey—or at least a temporary respite from the tempest.

But again, *serenely candid* suggests the manner in which the candour is expressed rather than the source of the candour.

Comment: It's not exactly a "natural pairing", but ***composedly** candid* probably associates more strongly with the candid person's mindset at the time, since it's not easy to imagine how it could modify the candour itself.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

> This is the most candid thing I’ve ever lucidly written.